# NetBeans Java Project will compile on Mac but not PC

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

I seem to be having an issue building and running a project written in NetBeans. It was originally written on a Macbook, and runs just fine, but when I try and run it from my PC I get the following errors:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:367)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:305)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:894)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:158)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
file:/C:/Users/K/Documents/Sample/captured-desktop/dist/run537474333/Captured.jar!/com/sample/captured/FXMLMainApp.fxml

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2617)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2595)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3230)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3191)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3164)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3140)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3120)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
at com.sample.captured.Captured.start(Captured.java:23)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$8.run(LauncherImpl.java:837)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$7.run(PlatformImpl.java:335)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:301)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(WinApplication.java:112)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sample.captured.FXMLMainAppController.fetchTagData(FXMLMainAppController.java:186)
at com.sample.captured.FXMLMainAppController.populateTableView(FXMLMainAppController.java:169)
at com.sample.captured.FXMLMainAppController.initializeTableView(FXMLMainAppController.java:163)
at com.sample.captured.FXMLMainAppController.initialize(FXMLMainAppController.java:114)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
... 19 more
Exception running application com.sample.captured.Captured
Java Result: 1
```

Is there a setting or directory or something somewhere that needs to be adjusted? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The FXMLLoader is failing, is the referenced fxml file in the Jar with the correct path, and is the jar also at the path that is being used?

Comment: Is there anything specific I should be looking for? I didn't write this code, and I am coming from Microsoft IDE, so I haven't a whole lot of experience in NetBeans.

Comment: I would ask the person whose project this is.